# AWS CLI list files based on a substring recursively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am new to AWS CLI and I am trying to find a way to list specific files like I could with RCLONE. I am looking to look through a directory recursively and list the file names based on a string.  In this case it is a year, so look for files that have the following in the file name...."*_2021*"

I am on a windows server to I tried to do a ls --recursive and then | FINDSTR, but it does not like the syntax.  The --exclude and --include only work with cp.

Comment: You can specify a prefix to ListObjectsV2 but you cannot specify a suffix or substring search; that's just how S3 ListObjects works.   I recommend you ask about your particular syntax issue with windows shell or whatever that is

Answer (score 0):

`aws s3 ls` outputs a human-friendly list of objects but it isn't great for consumption by other software.

An alternative syntax is to use [list-objects-v2 — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.33/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html):

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket foo --prefix my_directory/
```

This outputs as JSON (or `--text`) and is easier to consume and manipulate in other programs.

You can even become quite creative specifying `--query` parameters. See: [JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Or, since you are on Windows, you could also consider using [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/).